# how to remove brown outline from text field using phonegap +jquery

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I am using phonegap .Actually I saw brown outline from text field.I am working on OS 4.0.0 .
So I use css to remove that .

```
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);   
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
```

But After using this every thing is working fine But Problem is that when keyboard is open on clicking the Tab key it **print** (-) underscore. Can you please tell me how to remove this .?

is there any way to handle tab event ?

But If I remove this CSS tab click goes to next field .Why it not going to next field

Answer (score 0):

Use css for text field:

```
outline:0px;
```